# Grouping and Pipe delimiter (Newbee) SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I created this script:

```
SELECT Distinct 
      rtrim(Insurances.EligibilityPayorNumber) as InsurancePayorCode
    , rtrim(ContractFacilityProviders.NPI) as ProviderID
    , rtrim(PatientInsuranceProfiles.Insurance1PolicyNumber) as SubscriberInsuranceID
    , rtrim(PatientInsuranceProfiles.Insurance1PolicyGroupNumber) as SubscriberGroupNumber
    , rtrim(PatientDemographics.firstname) as SubscriberFirstName
    , rtrim(PatientDemographics.MiddleInitial) as SubscriberMiddleInitial
    , rtrim(PatientDemographics.Lastname) as SubscriberLastName
    , rtrim(PatientDemographics.sex) as Gender
    , rtrim(PatientDemographics.DateofBirth) as DOB
    , ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate as DateofService
    , PatientDemographics.AccountNumber as TrackingID
FROM ScheduleEntry
LEFT JOIN PatientDemographics
    ON ScheduleEntry.PatientAccount = PatientDemographics.AccountNumber
LEFT JOIN Reasons
    ON ScheduleEntry.ReasonCode = Reasons.ReasonCode
LEFT JOIN Providers
    ON ScheduleEntry.ResourceCode = Providers.MedStarProviderIdentifier
LEFT JOIN Facilities
    ON ScheduleEntry.FacilityCode = Facilities.MedStarFacilityIdentifier
LEFT JOIN [john-pc\sqlexpress].[Global].[dbo].[PatientStatuses] TAB2 
    on ScheduleEntry.PatientStatus = TAB2.PatientStatusCode
LEFT JOIN AddedResource 
    ON ScheduleEntry.ResourceCode = AddedResource.AddedResourceCode
LEFT JOIN Caregiver
    ON ScheduleEntry.ResourceCode = Caregiver.CaregiverCode
LEFT JOIN ReasonScripts
    ON ScheduleEntry.ReasonCode = ReasonScripts.Reasoncode
LEFT JOIN Scripts
    on Reasonscripts.Scriptcode = Scripts.ScriptCode
LEFT JOIN PatientInsuranceProfiles
    ON ScheduleEntry.PatientAccount = PatientInsuranceProfiles.PatientAccountNumber
LEFT JOIN Insurances
    ON PatientInsuranceProfiles.Insurance1Mnemonic = Insurances.Mnemonic
LEFT JOIN ContractFacilityProviders
    ON PatientDemographics.PrimaryPhysician = ContractFacilityProviders.ProviderIdentifier
WHERE ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate >= getdate()
    and ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate <= getDate() +1
    and PatientinsuranceProfiles.ActiveFlag = 1
    and EligibilityPayorNumber > = 1
ORDER By SCHEDULEDATE
```

I would like to do a few things and can't figure out how:

1. The DOB of is returning a value of `Nov 6 1939 12:00AM` and I need it to be `mmddyyyy`.
2. I need to group by `TrackingID` which can be the same on multiple lines. The data would always be the same.
3. What can I add to the script so when I run it as a SQL it will save as pipe delimited?

Comment: What is the data type of `DOB` column, if its not Datetime then in what format the datetime values are saved ?

Comment: 3) - `for xml path('')`

Comment: As for the date for DateOfBirth assuming it is a datetime field you can use `REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,PatientDemographics.DateofBirth,101),'/','') AS DOB`.  As a far as saving as pipe there is no native way I know of do do this in SQL.  You could add `+ '|'` to each of your fields, but you still have to export it.  I would use either the Powershell Export-Csv Cmdlet and replace the delimiter to a pipe or create an SSIS package with SQL Data Tools.  Both Powershell and Data Tools can run SQL native from their respective environments.

Comment: It is datetime. Where in the script do I put "REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,PatientDemographics.DateofBirth,101),'/','') AS DOB"

Comment: You can set the pipe character as a Customer Delimiter within the Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Text section of the Tools>Options dialog. Then when you select Results to Text on any new query you will have pipe delimited results.

Comment: Any of these help @JohnMolina

Answer (score 0):

For your DOB, this can be used in your SELECT. Note, it will be of type `VARCHAR` and no longer a datetime.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PatientDemographics.DateofBirth,101),'/','') AS DOB
```

I notice your `RTRIM` and they could be necessary for your output, but this is just some free knowledge on SQL server and trailing spaces for comparisions:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626

```
DECLARE @s1 varchar(10)
DECLARE @s2 varchar(10)

set @s1 = 'nospace'
set @s2 = '3spaces   '

select len(@s1), len(@s2)
```